# VividSolutions shapefilereader acts differently in Windows and Linux

Tags: java, shapefile, geotools

The Shapefilereader from Vivisolutions works perfectly in Windows, but in multiple ubuntu instances I get this error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 438
>       at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:906)
>       at java.lang.StringBuffer.substring(StringBuffer.java:482)
>       at org.geotools.dbffile.DbfFile.ParseRecordColumn(DbfFile.java:247)
>       at com.vividsolutions.jump.io.ShapefileReader.read(ShapefileReader.java:175)

Code for reading the shapefile is:

```
public static FeatureCollection readShapefile(String shpFile)
{
    File file = new File(shpFile);
    if (!file.exists())
        Application.logError("File does not exist " + file.getName());

    ShapefileReader reader = new ShapefileReader();
    FeatureCollection collection = null;
    try {
        collection = reader.read(new DriverProperties(shpFile));
    } catch (IllegalParametersException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return collection;
}
```

I ensured that both the windows machine and the ubuntu machine have the same version of java installed.

In ubuntu, java -version gives

> java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

In windows, java -version gives

> java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Is there any reason they would be behaving different?  Reading the error, the geotools dbffile parser runs into an issue. I've done a lot of searching and testing, the DBF file seems to be fine and can be read in multiple programs, including this one when run under windows.

Comment: can you share the shapefile?

Comment: what happens if you use the GeoTools shapefile store directly?